# Transition into a new set of ListView items?

Tags: java, android, listview

For example, I have a couple of String arrays and I've already set a list adapter:

```
String[] initial = new String[] {
        "Geometry",
        "Algebra",
        "Differentation Calculus",
        "Integral Calculus",
        "Trigonometry",
        "Algebra II",
        "Triangle",
        "Rectange"
};
String [] triangle = new String[] {
        "Area",
        "Perimeter"
};

String[] rectangle = new String[] {
        "Area",
        "Perimeter"
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, initial);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    ...
}
```

What should I have in my `onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long)` method that allows me to load a different set of list items WITHOUT having to create a new activity.

Comment: when you click on "Triangle" of your initial list item set you want to set to the adapter a new set pointing to triangle String[] ?

Comment: Exactly what I'm talking about @Franco.

Comment: well, can test the code post below, or try with an ExpandableListView, i think is the best choice, and you dont have to worry about data set changing issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this, you'll be always changing the adapter dataset, i don´t know if is the best option. I have a similar use case, i.e. when i select 'Triangle' in the initial String[] i show an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) with the child items of the initial 'Triangle' data set...

in the other way i think you can do this way... (i have no tested this)

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

     if(adapter.getItem(position).equals("Triangle")){
         adapter.clear();
         for(String item : triangle){
            adapter.add(item);
         }
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }else if(...)
}
```